# What does that ae stand for next to the YouTube symbol?

Tags: youtube

Please answer quickly, i'm getting suspicious about my Internet company.

Comment: America Eastern Time

Answer (score 1):

The two letters refer to the country code. In this case, AE should refer to United Arab Emirates.